# json showing duplicate output of mysql result

Tags: php, json

I am trying to print json_encode and I get output duplicated. I am certain there is one single record in database and yet it shows the same record data twice in various format. This is it:

```
[{"0":"Polo","name":"Polo","1":"City ","location":"City ","2":"Manama","city":"Manama"}]
```

The code behind this is:

```
$dataArray = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dataArray[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($dataArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Any idea?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Sure thing. Will rewrite the php service soon to be OOP based. For now just testing for android sake

Comment: If you edit to mysqli_fetch_array in the question, I can up vote it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the default behavior of [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is to return both a column name and index keyed array.

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or set the second parameter of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dataArray[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: aye dont know how it skipped me! I used assoc and now working fine. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You should set another fetch style. It now fetches all columns using both their 0 based index and their name.

This should work as expected:

```
$dataArray = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $dataArray[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($dataArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because you can access the results either by name or by column index, but you're serializing the entire thing, so both ways of getting the data are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//$dataArray = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dataArray[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($dataArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I commented first line. Because you used like that $dataArray[].