# Columns are not shown in PHP querty but are shown in the phpmyadmin interface for MariaDB

Tags: php, json, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I wrote a simple PHP script to provide me some data, but I can't get all the columns to be shown ( as a JSON string), but in the PHPmyadmin frontend for the latest MariaDB all columns are shown. The interesting thing about this error is that through the same script another query (different POST variable value) shows all the expected columns. Also the order gets messed up in the first query.

My result in the PHP script:

```
{"id":"2","name":"it","mail":"john.doe@contoso.com","surname":"john"}
```

Expected result (also shown in Phpmyadmin as rows in the correct query order):

```
{"id":"2","name":"john","surname":"doe", "department":"it","mail":"john.doe@contoso.com"}
```

The order error I can fix with some dirty tricks (last option), but the columns are the real problem. Is there a column limit in MariaDB or/and PHP? I am not sure what to look for to resolve this error.

PS: I googled around and someone on the official MariaDB site says there is a [1000](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/maximum-number-of-columns/)(I am using the same storage engine) column limit. I also checked

```
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth))
    {
    $rows[] = $r;
    }
```

and 
       `while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)){$rows[] = $r;}`

The second  option gives me everything I would like to receive, still it isn't the desired result because, everything is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867470/json-showing-duplicate-output-of-mysql-result). The only lines after this loop are

```
echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($link);?>
```

**What the I and and the community discovered:**

1.`$rows[0] = $r;` >>displays only one record, but still not in the correct format.

2. `array_push($rows,$r);` >> does not do the trick.
3. `echo json_encode($rows[0]);` and `print_r($rows[0])` >> `{"ID":"6","Name":"IT Department","Surname":"Doe","Email":"john.doe@contoso.com","‌​DeparmentRole":"Main‌​tanacei","Available"‌​:"Everyday from 8am to 17pm","Phone Number":"44 1206 256000","Office":"A1-Maitanance","CompanyRank":"standard employee"}` and same for the print_r.

Comment: What if you use `$rows[0] = $r;`

Comment: It's the same result. Also `array_push($rows,$r);` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Please provide both `echo json_encode($rows[0]);` and `print_r($rows[0]);`

Comment: echo result: `{"ID":"6","Name":"IT Department","Surname":"Doe","Email":"john.doe@contoso.com","DeparmentRole":"Maintanacei","Available":"Everyday from 8am to 17pm","Phone Number":"44 1206 256000","Office":"A1-Maitanance","CompanyRank":"standard employee"}` The data of the print_r is the same only the formatting is different ( `Array([ID]=>6,...)`. When I copy the exact same query to the phpmyadmin interface and run it in the database I get additional columns and the values are at their right places (Name > John, Department => IT,...).

Comment: @Hackerman the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a close observation did the trick. I created a two tables with  the same column name. It is nothing wrong when we have two columns, but when we join them we can have a real mess, the original column has been overwritten by the joined one, what also explained, why the order was messed up.
**So remember** 
Having **two columns** in **tables that can "be on their own"** is **OK**, but when **joining them ALL columns MUST HAVE an UNIQUE name**. What I do not understand, why the AS keyword failed to display it with an alias and took the regular column name.